# Query a timestamp range in supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have a table in my supabase database with two columns `start` end `end`. Both are of type `timestampz`. Now I want to query all entries where the current timestamp (`Date.now()`) is inbetween `start` and `end`.

I thought I could do something like this (TypeScript):

```
var currentTimestamp = Date.now();
await serviceSupbaseClient
        .from("table")
        .select(
          "id, name, start, end"
        )
        .gte("start", currentTimestamp)
        .lte("end", currentTimestamp)
        .single()
```

But this does not work. I also tried formatting my `currentTimestamp` in the same String iso format that I get from the select.

Is this something that is not possible to do with postgrest supabase? Or what am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
This is my entry in my supabase db (start/end has different name.):
[image]

and my current Code is this:

```
var currentTimestamp = Date();
console.log(currentTimestamp);
await serviceSupbaseClient
    .from("lobby")
    .select(
      "id, name, valid_from, valid_to"
    )
    .lte("valid_from", currentTimestamp)
    .gte("valid_to", currentTimestamp)
    .single()
```

I get this error:

```
'invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "Fri Jan 26 2024 12:35:28 GMT+0000 (Coordina'
```

when using
`var currentTimestamp = Date.now();`

I get this error:
`date/time field value out of range: "1706272571131"`

Comment: You say "But this does not work", but what exactly happens? Does it return the wrong data? Does it return an error? In your example, you are querying data that are greater than or equal to the current time stamp, and also less than or equal to the current timestamp. Such data most likely does not exist.

Comment: @dshukertjr It returns nothing. I compare different column values to my current time stamp. The data exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the start time and end time in the wrong place. Your start time needs to be earlier than the current timestamp, and the end time needs to be later than the current timestamp. Flip your `lte` and `gte`, and you should see some data.

```js
var currentTimestamp = new Date().toISOString();
const {data, error} = await serviceSupbaseClient
        .from("table")
        .select(
          "id, name, start, end"
        )
        .lte("start", currentTimestamp)
        .gte("end", currentTimestamp)
        .single()
```

Comment: Actually this does not change a thing in my case. I always get no results back.

Comment: @progNewbie I have just edited my answer right now. Try converting the Date object to `toIso8601String`. If this does not work, I will need to see some sample data that you have which you think will be queried using the query you shared.

Comment: In what package is `toIso8601String` included? (I am in Typescript Edge function) And isn't this converting it to local time? On the Supabase DB it is UTC per default.

Comment: @progNewbie My bad, I thought it was Dart. I have edited my answer to a Typescript format.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly this doesn't fix it. I just always get null in return. I edited my question with further information.

Comment: In that case, you most likely do not have any data in your database that satisfies the condition. If the data is `null`, and you will get an error. What error message are you getting?

Comment: As I said, I edited my question. There I put the information about the data in my database and the error message :)

Comment: @progNewbie Okay, try `new Date().toISOString()` for the timestamp. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: This worked! thank you so much. I hope this will be reflected in the docs someday :)